# Allow access to per-site meta posts' code via edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, markdown, per-site-meta

The `edit` option is useful not only to edit, but also (and more importantly to me) to know/copy-paste the code that the user has typed in to obtain the given display.

Yet when I try to use this on meta, I run into

> Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.

This is particularly annoying when you're looking up a question about formatting and the answer doesn't include the raw code.

Comment: One can do inspect element too, for the harder way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a workaround for this:

1. Go to the revision list (by clicking the 'edited [timestamp]' link underneath the post if it's there, or by manually entering the URL to `/posts/[post id]/revisions`, e.g.: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5020/revisions)

   [image]
2. Click the 'source' link of the revision you want to see the Markdown for:

   [image]
3. Profit!

   [image]

Another option would be to use the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=5020&filter=!.UDo6l2ikDi7cRwv&site=math.meta&run=true) but since it returns JSON, the Markdown will be escaped (e.g. backslashes are duplicated). For 'casual' users it's less useful than the procedure described above.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks!