# Can't edit questions on meta posts; unable to gain reputation on them

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

I wanted to edit [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32766/reaching-question-limit-problem)'s title which is on Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange because it did not have anything to do with the question itself. However, I could not edit it. When I tried to edit it, it brought me this message:

> Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.

Then, someone else came to edit the question's title. He was **not** a moderator, he just had way more reputation than me (I had 159, and he had 10k+).

You also cannot gain privileges in Meta. At least that was what I saw in the Activity tab. So do I have to get 2k reputation on the main site to edit it, or is there something wrong? I'm relatively new to the site, and I rarely use Meta.

Comment: @muru Again, that question doesn't address a part of this question, which is how per-site meta rep is linked to main site rep. That's not currently explained well in any meta post, I searched, and is only covered well in the help center (which we can't close as duplicates against).

Comment: For this question not to be a duplicate (part of it clearly is) I think it needs to be edited to focus on a part that clearly is not.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223885/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87890/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129033/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247809/282094

Comment: The canonical is *[Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites)*.

Comment: To duplicate close voters: this was **already closed as a duplicate of that question, and subsequently reopened**. As I said in my above comment, there's a significant part of this question that is **not** addressed in that question or in any other post here on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow access to per-site meta posts' code via edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333835/allow-access-to-per-site-meta-posts-code-via-edit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reputation on **per-site** metas is derived straight from the corresponding main site, and privileges you earned there will be carried over to the meta site.

See the [help center page on per-site metas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation **is the same as your reputation on Mathematics Stack Exchange** (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation [on the main site] to participate on meta.

Note that **this** site, Meta Stack Exchange, works differently: as this site isn't linked to a single particular main Q&A site, this site has its own reputation and privileges earned for participation here. This is the opposite of how things work on **site** metas.

As far as why per-site metas don't allow suggested edits, this was because at the time that rule was established nearly a decade ago, per-site metas [had very low traffic and not enough people were reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites), and it just...never got changed. There's an [active feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129033/allow-suggested-edits-on-site-metas-and-show-them-in-the-main-site-queue) asking that this be changed, which you can [support](/a/306398).